# Telethon SendReactionRequest: a TLObject was expected but found something else

Tags: python, telegram, channel, telethon, tlc

This represent the Telethon request to send the reaction on the post of the public channel.when run the code I got some error when the code try to run this "SendReactionRequest" they catch the error of TLC object

```
import asyncio
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendReactionRequest

async def send_reaction(client, chat_id, message_id):
    try:
        await client(SendReactionRequest(
            peer=chat_id,
            msg_id=message_id,
            big=True,
            add_to_recent=True,
            reaction=''
        ))
        print('Reaction sent successfully')
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending reaction:", str(e))

async def main(phone):
    async with TelegramClient(f'sessions/{phone}', APIID, 'HashXXXX') as client:
        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            print(f'{phone} needs to be authenticated by OTP')
            return

        chat_id = 'ViewTestChannel12'
        message_id = 9

        await send_reaction(client, chat_id, message_id)

with open('phone.csv', 'r') as file:
    phones = file.read().splitlines()

async def run_main():
    for phone in phones:
        await main(phone)

asyncio.run(run_main())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Raw API (when you use `client(SomeRequest(...))`) is subject to change across minor versions of the library. In this case, older versions of the request used just a string for the emoji, but it is now (as of v1.29) a [`Reaction`](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/reaction.html) as you can see in [`SendReactionRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/send_reaction.html):

```
result = client(functions.messages.SendReactionRequest(
    peer=chat_id,
    msg_id=message_id,
    big=True,
    add_to_recent=True,
    reaction=[types.ReactionEmoji(
        emoticon=''
    )]
))
```

(If copy pasting the emoji doesn't work, try using the correct unicode escape sequence.)